# Passing parameter to window.location.href fails

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass the currently logged in Azure AD user identity into the ajax method so it can be used as the input parameter in the  `window.location.href`

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var orderedQuantity = $("#txt").val();
        var orderId = $("#orderId").val();
        var data = {
            orderId: orderId,
            orderedQuantity: orderedQuantity,
        }
        var loggedUser = @User.Identity.Name;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("EditItem", "Orders")',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status === "NotAvailable") {
                   $("#errorMessage").val("Enter a valid Quantity");
                }
                else {
                    var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")';
                    window.location.href = url + "?custEmail="+loggedUser;
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I am storing the `@User.Identity.Name;` in the `loggedUser`  variable and using it as the input paramter in the `window.location.href = url + "?custEmail="+loggedUser;`. It throws error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

[image]

Can anyone say if I am missing anything here.. I am passing the input paramter to the Orders page like this in other places and it fails in ajax method. I even tried to like below

```
var loggedUser = User.Identity.Name;
```

It even errors out like `Uncaught ReferenceError: User is not defined`

[image]

Can anyone suggest what is that I am missing here

Comment: You cannnot do like this, because current state would not persist in else cluse, could you please share your `url + "?custEmail="+loggedUser` method signature?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I am not sure I am following you .I want the URL to be like `https://localhost:44330/Orders?custEmail=xyz@abc.org`

Comment: Well could you double check if the user in current session?  `var loggedUser = '@User.Identity.Name'; console.log(loggedUser);` or share how you are getting current login user.

Comment: One easy way to trigger your problem, `1. First assign dummy value on var loggedUser = "testuser@outlook.com"` then watch if the request goes well.  If step 1 goes well then check your `@User.Identity.Name` because it means user not in session. I have tested locally its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add quotation marks like below:

```
var loggedUser = "@User.Identity.Name";  //or `@User.Identity.Name`
```

Comment: Both didnot work

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I am getting the `"@User.Identity.Name"` string in the URL... But I am trying pass the currently logged in user

Comment: The URL is now looking like `https://localhost:44330/Orders?custEmail=User.Identity.Name` but I wanted it to pass the logged in user identity from AzureAD `https://localhost:44330/Orders?custEmail=xyz@abc.org`

Comment: It seems to be unbelievable. @User.Identity.Name will generate the value when app runs no matter you use ` ` or `" "` or `' '`. Are your sure you use `@User` instead of `User`?